# hibernate grandfather , parent ,child mapping problem

Tags: hibernate, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have a problem where I have this three grandfather parent and child 
and I am trying to get from parent all his children he gives me an half of is children odd as it seemes I just cant understand why can someone please help me ?

this is the case:

```
      parentDao.getChildrenSet();//problem... return half every time
      parentDao.getChildrenWithSqlQuery();//works o.k but it's not the way to work
```

I think my problem is in the mapping therefore guidance would b appreciated
thanks.

Notice : every entity got her get/set empty c'tor hash and equals
(without the mapping entitys inside hash and equals)

### **EDIT**:i am not using embedded id , my boss desiccation there are pro's and con's and this is what he has thought ...

grandfather:

```
  @Entity
@Table(name = "grandfather")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "grandfather_SEQ", sequenceName = "grandfather_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
public class ComponentTreeProfile extends TrackableEntity {

// id
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "grandfather_SEQ")
@Column(name = "grandfather_ID")
private Integer grandfatherId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "grandfather")
private Set<Parent> parent;
        //some info equals, hashcode empty c'tor ...}
```

---

parent

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "parent")
  public class Parent  extends TrackableEntity implements
    Serializable {
  @Id
@Column(name = "grandfather_ID", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
private Integer grandfatherId;
@Id
    //seq is taking cared
@Column(name = "parent_ID", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
private Integer profileModelId;
    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "grandfather_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Grandfather grandfather;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Child> child = new LinkedList<Child>();}
```

---

child

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "Child")
public class Child extends TrackableEntity implements
        Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2451336147838275971L;
// id's fields

@Id
@Column(name = "grandfather_ID", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
private Integer profileId;
@Id
@Column(name = "Parent_ID", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
private Integer ParentId;
@Id
    //seq is being handled 
@Column(name = "child_ID", nullable = false)
private Integer ChildTypeId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "grandFather_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "parent_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
private Parent parent;}
```

---

Comment: Are you using @IdClass on the parent class? You have 2 attributes annotated with @Id, but I can't see the @IdClass annotation..

Comment: @Augusto I am not familiar with @IdClass about @embeddedId see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Parent class, the id is not properly mapped and you're mapping the same column twice. Mapping the column twice is not a problem, but it can be avoided by mapping Grandfather as part of the id. You have an example of how to do this on the [hibernate annotations documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177).

#### Edit

I just read the documentation myself and found that Hibernate now supports to have more than one

column annotated with @Id, without defining an Embedded id or IdClass. 
I reckon that hibernate is having trouble to recognize in which order it should use the 2 integers to map the Parent.

Try adding the parameters `referencedColumnName` on both @JoinColumn in Child.parent.

Comment: can you please explain what is wrong with my mapping ' I have already read some document's and I'am clueless about why it does'nt work well ' it dies run but gives a coupling to a given parent ...